# Apply jQuery UI widgets to ajax loaded elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to activate the jQueryUI button widget on a given selector, lets say '.button'.

Whats the best way to automatically activate the widget on any new '.button' elements inserted to the DOM after the initial page load via ajax.

Previously, I used the livePlugin with code something like this:

```
$('.button')
    .live(function(){
        $(this).button();
    })
```

Since 'live' has been moved to the jQuery core the live function requires an event type as the first parameter so this is no longer possible. Is there alternative method within the jQuery core that will achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options here.  First, there's the [liveQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/), like this:

```
$(.button).liveQuery(function() { $(this).button(); });
```

Another alternative is to call the selector on your elements when you load them,  this for example finds all `.button` **only** in the response, so doesn't mess with existing elements before the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'page.html'
   success: function(data) {
     //stuff...
     $('.button', data).button();
   }
});
```

Another similar approach if you have a lot going on is to have your plugins in a function like this:

```
function rigUI(context) {
  $('.button', context).button();
  $('.date', context).datepicker();
}

$(rigUI); // Load at document.ready, default context is document

//in ajax load love above call: rigUI(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had considered using the liveQuery plugin but the second approach seems a lot more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Since all jquery commands have a uniform structure it is really easy to use any object (including json data from a ajax request) as a jquery command

Sample:

```
var jc = {
    'selector': '#sample',
    'method': 'dialog',
    'options': {'title': 'I am a sample'}
}

$(jc.selector)[jc.method](jc.options);
```

is the same as

$('#sample').dialog({'title': "I am a sample}};

http://jsfiddle.net/wb5Ee/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to liveQuery as it seemed outdated to me as I could not make it work :

https://github.com/bapplistudio/jquery.build

- You need to declare all your jquery activations into **$("body").build(function(){ }); ** statements
- You need to call $("newelement").build(); to call back all your initialisation functions.

Look at the documentation on the jquery.build site for more information and examples and the live demo similar to your case.

http://saf.re/github/jquery.build/examples/simple.html