# Html response from Jquery not working with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, ajax

I have find a lot of posts similar to this question but I don't think I'm doing it wrong since I'm not putting javascript in the response of the ajax call.

Basically the ajax returns pure html that is put inside a div. This div is inside my page and the page already contains references to css and javascript files.

In one of those javascript files I try to render the buttons returned by the ajax call to look nice with a jquery ui function so basically what I do is this

```
$(".ButtonClass").button();
```

This piece of code is in the document.ready function, and the html returned by ajax includes the "ButtonClass" for all the buttons.

The `.button()` works for a button outside the returned ajax html, but it does not work for elements returned by the ajax call.

I think it should work because css styles are applied to the results but I cannot get any function to work with the results, i repeat I don't return javascript code I have this code in an external file which is referenced in the whole page.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559924/apply-jquery-ui-widgets-to-ajax-loaded-elements

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable buttons for elements returned by the AJAX request, you should execute it again when receiving the response.

`.button()` is executed on the elements that have been selected at the time it was called - which does not include the AJAX ones when called before the AJAX request was made.

Please do note that `$(".ButtonClass")` will also include previous `.ButtonClass` elements, so they will be converted to buttons twice. You'd have to select only the ones from the AJAX response.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
$(".ButtonClass").button();
```

In ajax callback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to apply your decorator function when the ajax call has been succesfully terminated.
Something along this lines:

```
$('#myelement').load('script.php', function() {

   // Now the page has some more button to decorate:
   $(".ButtonClass .ugly").button().removeClass('ugly'); 

});
```

As you may see I added a "ugly" class to the new buttons, so to not re-beautify the already beatiful buttons present :)

Answer (score 1):

The .button() function must be called every time new markup is introduced in the page that should be a button. You do this correctly on .ready(), but you should also do it on the success function of the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initialize these buttons after you populate your div.

If your div is stored in, for instance, a javascript variable called `$container`, then run the code `$('.ButtonClass',$container).button()` after you have added this content to your page.

Answer (score 0):

in your callback for the ajax, do this `$(".ButtonClass").button();` again.