# jQuery, apply .buttonset to an element that's not yet loaded

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-widgets

I have the following code working nicely:

```
    $field2.on("change", "#selector", function(){
        $field2.load("./index.php?show-options=true", { value: $(this).val() }, function() {
        $("#options").buttonset();
        });
    });
```

It loads the `#options` div and applies button to anchor tags within it.

Is there a way to declare

```
$("#options").buttonset();
```

BEFORE the `#options` div is loaded?

I looked through jQuery docs with no success, and also found this answer:

[Apply jQuery UI widgets to ajax loaded elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559924/apply-jquery-ui-widgets-to-ajax-loaded-elements)

which I think might be on track, but haven't understood it fully nor managed to implement.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following:

```
$field2.on("change", "#selector", function(){
    $field2.load("./index.php?show-options=true", { value: $(this).val() }, function() {
      $field2.find("#options").buttonset();
    });
});
```

Will make all option elements within $field2 into a button set (once the content has been updated).

Or alternatively you could make the button set on dom ready:

```
$(function() { $("#options").buttonset(); });
```

**Update**

jQuery selectors work on elements in the DOM (unless given a context), if the element is not in the DOM then unfortunately jQuery will not be able to affect it directly. If the load then call to buttonset is causing a FOUC (flash of unstyled content), you could try the following:

```
$field2.on("change", "#selector", function() {
    $field2.empty();
    $.get("./index.php?show-options=true", { value: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
      var newContent = $(data);
      $("#options", newContent).buttonset();
      $field2.empty().append(newContent);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to have ("#options").buttonset() declared before .load. When I declare it after .load it works even without .find.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the original code other than having a more specific selector. It's still creating the buttonset as callback on the load function, just like the original.

Comment: @Freelancer At which point in time do you want the element with id options to become a buttonset? OnDomReady, when #selector changes or in response to another event?

Comment: @rich.okelly: onDomReady I guess. I want #options to become buttonset from the moment it's loaded, but I want to declare it before #options is loaded. Is this possible?

Comment: @Freelancer Unfortunately not, you can only make it a buttonset once it exists (ie is loaded).

Comment: @rich.okelly:  Thanks. If you post it as answer, I'll mark it.