# How to implement JavaScript function on the DOM html form <select> element loaded from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch the edit form of HTML in which I have a select tag with class name class="selectpicker" for which I need "bootstrap-select.js" to be loaded after the form. The form  tag was working fine if I called it from the same page. But now as I am trying to call it with Ajax when the edit button is pressed, the JavaScript property is not working on the  tag, as it is getting loaded after the above JavaScript file is executed at the start. How can I solve this issue?

```
<select 
  class="selectpicker"  
  name="keyword[]" 
  id="keyword[]" 
  data-placeholder="Start typing... " 
  style="width: 100%;" 
  multiple  
  required
>
  <option>Dance</option>
  <option>Music</option>
  <option>Sports</option>
  <option>Poster</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you explain more with your code?

Comment: By AJAX do you mean you are loading the `<select>` element into the page via AJAX, and the select list is not showing up as a bootstrap select picker?

Comment: yes @BrianMains you are right! same issue, Because i am fetching the html form in which <select> tag is there. This was not the problem if the html form was in the same page.

Comment: OK in that scenario, after the AJAX loading of the select element, you have to re-register the plugin, manually using the API function.

Comment: @BrianMains dude how to do it? do i need to call the function manually?

Comment: Yes you have to call the widget manually; I don't know what the widget name is otherwise I would have included a brief sample.  See this example (I'm not sure if the "live" method approach is still supported): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559924/apply-jquery-ui-widgets-to-ajax-loaded-elements

Answer (score 0):

The 'change' event will bubble up through the DOM. I presume you're putting your fetched HTML into some sort of container, yes? Put a 'change' event listener on the container:

```
container.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    if (e.target.tagName == 'select' && e.target.classList.contains('selectpicker'))
        doSomething();
});
```

Comment: With jQuery that becomes `container.on('change', 'select.selectpicker', doSomething);`

Comment: I am putting the whole html form it into
 <div id="create_event_popup">
</div>

Comment: so `var container = document.getElementById("create_event_popup");` and then proceed with the rest.

Comment: Could you be more specific ... ?